# To get good answers ask a good question!

Tags: discussion

No really, [scientists have proved it](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/522171/data-mining-reveals-the-secret-to-getting-good-answers/) using our fellows over at Stack Overflow as guinea pigs. I wonder if there's enough questions on the PhysicsSE for a similar analysis to be meaningful ...

Comment: We're somewhat *unpredictable* :P

Comment: Terrible question :-p  But really interesting link!